Пытался конвертировать строку в число: input() через int()
user_num = input("Serg")
any_num = int(user_num)

print(any_num)
print(type(any_num))

Visual Studio Code выводит только: Serg
А тип переменной: type(any_num) не выводится.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
Спасибо!

Это какой-то глюк, должно всё выводиться

Если в переменной user_num не будет введено целое число, возникнет ошибка.

Функция input() отвечает за приём пользовательского ввода. Когда вы запускаете программу, она будет приостановлена до тех пор, пока вы не введёте какие-то данные. То что вы написали в качестве аргумента функции - будет выведено в консоли.
Затем в вы преобразовываете тип переменной user_num из str в int.
Если не форматировать ваш код, а выполнить его как есть, то получим в консоли следующее:
Serg123
123
<class 'int'>

Ошибки в коде нет.
